# Error installing pg gem after running bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, postgresql, osx-elcapitan

I'm on Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.6):

When trying to run `bundle`, I get an error after it tries to install `pg`.

Trying to run `gem install pg` also fails.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It's solved now, as you can see from the below answer. But the error was: `Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension... Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Note: Before doing the below steps, make sure you have **Xcode** installed, and  **homebrew**.

1. `brew install postgresql`
2. `gem uninstall pg` - this might not return anything, that's ok.
3. either `bundle install` in your application's root or `gem install pg`